# Basis swap spread pricing and bootstrapping

Tags: option-pricing, swaps, interest-rate-swap, convexity, cms

[image]

Here is the expression of a basis floating versus floating swap where the first term is a forward CMS Swap leg and the second one is a forward BOR leg where X is the margin that would make equal both leg?

Suppose X and all other parameters are know except the CA term? How can I express the CA term related to the others?

Comment: Any reply please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, not being an expert in basis swap pricing, this is just algebra -

$$
X_{n,c} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \left( S_{i,c}'(0) + {\rm\bf CA}(S_{i,c}'; \delta)\right) P(0,T_i')}{\sum_{i=1}^n P(0,T_i')} - \frac{1 - P(0,T_n')}{\delta \sum_{i=1}^n P(0,T_i')}
$$

which rearranges to

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n {\rm\bf CA}(S_{i,c}'; \delta) P(0,T_i')  =  - \sum_{i=1}^n S_{i,c}'(0)P(0,T_i') + \frac{1 - P(0,T_n')}{\delta} + X_{n,c} \sum_{i=1}^n P(0,T_i')
$$

You can't reduce it any further, since there are multiple **CA** terms (one for each $i$) not just one.

---

As pointed out in the comments, you can *bootstrap* the curve if you have $X_{n,c}$ for multiple $n$. For example, for $n = 1$ you can derive

$$
{\rm\bf CA}(S_{1,c}'; \delta) =  - S_{1,c}'(0) + \frac{1 - P(0,T_1')}{\delta} + X_{1,c}
$$

For any other $n$, assuming that you have already computed ${\rm\bf CA}(S_{k,c}';\delta)$ for $k=1,\dots,n-1$ then then you have

$$
{\rm\bf CA}(S_{n,c}';\delta)  = \frac{ - \sum_{i=1}^n S_{i,c}'(0)P(0,T_i') + \frac{1 - P(0,T_n')}{\delta} + X_{n,c} \sum_{i=1}^n P(0,T_i') - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} {\rm\bf CA}(S_{i,c}'; \delta) P(0,T_i') }{P(0,T_n') }
$$

which allows you to compute all values of ${\rm\bf CA}(S_{n,c}';\delta)$ iteratively.

Comment: pretty sure this is the point of bootstrapping though - you set n=1, that makes the algebra tractable for what you have, solve that, and the sub it into the equation for n=2, and then repeat...